# Can't update date in aspx to a MS-ACCESS table

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, oledbconnection

Hello I'm having problem with updating datatypes

I insert the date in the C# part like this

```
string strSQL = "INSERT into Frettir (CreatedBy,CreatedOn,Title,Description,Starts,Ends,CatId,SectionId,ArticleExt,Myndatexti,MyndUrAlbumi,NrMyndar) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Starts",OleDbType.Date).Value = dstartdate;
```

but I update in the aspx part like this

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Frettir] SET [Title]=@Title,[Description]=@Description,[CreatedBy]=@notandaID,[ArticleExt]=@ArticleExt, [Myndatexti]=@Myndatexti,[Starts]=@Starts WHERE [ArticleID]=@id2 "

 <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="notandaID"  Type="int16" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ArticleExt" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Myndatexti" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Starts" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id2" QueryStringField="ArticleID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I get an error Data type mismatch in criteria expression 
It seems that there are some type differences between the type that is input in the c# part and the aspx-part

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is not something I ever do (I'm an Access programmer), but I've read answers to questions like this so often, that I wonder if the problem is that you're not passing your parameters in order? The Jet/ACE provider doesn't recognize named parameters, so you have to be sure they're passed in the declared order. But I could be misinterpreting the situation.

Comment: NO, the insert works just fine,  and the update parameters are in the right order,  it just that it seems that the insert sentence seems to use some other format of the date even though it looks all right,  which causes the update sentence to fail.

Comment: Within Access and Jet/ACE SQL (i.e., if you're passing it directly to Jet/ACE), the # delimiter is used for dates, and not "'". Try [CreatedBy]=#@notandaID# and see if that makes a difference (I kind of doubt it will, but it's what you'd do within Access/Jet/ACE, and may be the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I just did it once... I assigned the valued using the following code..

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpDoj", EmpDoj.ToShortDateString());
```

It worked for me.. Thought it could help you as well...

Further, I'm eager to know the answer, why yours was not working...